# List all routes with the settings in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I wonder if there is a way to list all routes in my application. My application is using symfony 2.1

The order router:

- debug only shows routes with optional parameter values.
  E.g.

  app_product_distributors ANY / local _ {} / {} choose_distributor /

I would like the routes with the possible values of the parameters to avoid listing all controllers etc. in my routing.yml

E.g.

```
app_product_distributors ANY / local _ {} / {} choose_distributor / _locale with: en | fr _choose_distributor: choose_distributor | choisir_fournisseur
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Could you translate your question in english?

Comment: Presque tout les personnes utilisant stack overflow seulement sait parler anglais, pas de français. Comme ça, la langue préféré est anglais.

Comment: haha thanks to google translator :P

Comment: @Randrian Don't say that english is THE favorite language, (even if it is for you), just say that is the official language... Be diplomatic is not expensive...

Comment: I'm not sure that it is natively possible. Maybe, I'm wrong... If you have defined your routing in yaml format, you should be able to parse the config file in a console command...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic command to display `routing.yml` in console.

1. Considering `routing.yml` path = `app/config/routing.yml`
2. Create `DumpRoutingCommand.php` in `src/AppBundle/Command/`

...

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class DumpRoutingCommand extends Command
{
     protected function configure()
     {
        $this
            ->setName('routing:dump')
            ->setDescription('Displays routing.yml in console')
        ;
     }

     protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
     {
        $output->writeln(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../app/config/routing.yml'));
     }
}
```

Then, launch `php app/console routing:dump`

Hope it will help you.